# Having UILabel update based on Audio Player current time

Tags: swift, swift3, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession, audio-player

I am attempting to have my UILabel update based on the duration of what the AudioPlayer current time is. I don't want to use a timer, because within my app people will be recording themselves with small durations & the half seconds are important, so I wouldn't really want to use timer(). Instead what I am attempting to do is just have the label update based on what the current time is automatically. I can't however seem to figure it out...

Here is how I am going about it, but clearly I am not doing it correctly

```
var audioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer!

    var audioTime = UILabel() {
        didSet {
            do {
                try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioURL!)
                let currentTime = Int(audioPlayer.currentTime)
                let minutes = currentTime/60
                let seconds = currentTime - minutes * 60
                audioTime.text = (NSString(format: "%02d:%02d", minutes,seconds) as String)

            } catch {

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you! Connect Outlet to showTimeLbl and try.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var showTimeLbl: UILabel!
var timeCount:Int = 0
var timer:Timer!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    if(timer != nil)
    {
        timer.invalidate()
    }
    timer = Timer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.timerDidFire), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    RunLoop.current.add(timer, forMode: RunLoopMode.commonModes)

}

func timerDidFire()
{
    timeCount += 1

    showTimeLbl.text = NSString(format: "%02d:%02d:%02d", timeCount/3600,(timeCount/60)%60,timeCount%60) as String

}
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(true)
    timer?.invalidate()
    timer = nil
}
```